# Prove that Newton method converges for all values in this interval

Tags: convergence-divergence, newton-raphson

Let $f(x) = x^3-2$. Define a recursive sequence that converges to the root and prove that it converges to that root for all initial values within $[1,2]$.

I can define a recursive sequence but i don't know how to prove  convergence.

Comment: Your recursive sequence should be of the form $x_{k+1}=g(x_k)$. Provided you have an interval $I$ such that $g$ maps $I$ into itself and $|g'(x)|<1$ on $I$, you have convergence for any initial condition in $I$. This is a variant of a theorem called either the contraction mapping principle or the Banach fixed point theorem. The difficult part of this is usually ensuring that $g$ maps $I$ into itself.

Comment: Notice this difference: $f(x)$=$x^3$-$2$ versus $f(x)=x^3-2$.  The latter is inside just one pair of dollar signs, resulting in all the typesetting conventions used in mathematical notation being followed.  That's the right way to do it.  I changed this in the question. $\qquad$